# I'm rather new to programming and sorta wandered into trying to have globals :\ C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, global

At the moment, I have like 9 different functions while only a couple of them actually do anything - a shop, main, and selection screen. I want my currency to be globalized in the selection screen and doing #inculde "shop.cpp" does not work, it just gives me the error saying that shop.obj is already defined: The code for the shop is a bit long, so I'll just post the first few lines, up to where I want the globalized variable to actually come into use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gp.cpp"
using namespace std;

double smallNet = 0, bronzeAxe = 0;
int availableGP;
int skillselection();

int shop()
{
    int itemPurchase = 0;
    double shopCont = 0;

    cout << " \n\n\n\nWelcome to the General Store.";
    cout << "\n We sell many supplies, you";
    cout << "\n will need throughout your";
    cout << "\n adventure! Please take a look!";

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    while (shopCont != 2)
    {
        system("cls");

        cout << "________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "|_______Item_______|___Cost____|" << endl;
        cout << "| Small Net     (1)| 10gp      |" << endl;
        cout << "| Bronze Axe    (2)| 100gp     |" << endl;
        cout << "|__________________|___________|" << endl;
        cout << "Gold: " << availableGP << endl;
```

This next snippet of code is from the gp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gp()
{
    int availableGP = 112;
    return availableGP;
}
```

I know I said I wanted it to be called from the selection screen - but The code isn't going into code boxes :\ so this is gonna look bad. As I said in the beginning, I'm pretty rudimentary with code so dont go and have me put in std::iostream=array::index or something like that lol

The error message that I get when I try to compile:
shop.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl gp(void)" (?gp@@YAHXZ) already defined in gp.obj

What exactly does that "cdecl gp(void)" mean? I don't have any voids in my program. And I don't know what the ?gp@@YAHXZ thing means either :\ I feel like I need to retake my C++ class cause teacher has only made us program 3 times, and its going on the 12th week... lecture lecture lecture... kinda annoying

Sorry if this is a stupidly repeated question, but I don't know what any of the special stuff everyone uses is, like .h files or conio or something like that :\ I've only had to make things that worked in main, so... this is a huge step up from that... because I got bored and wanted to figure out what would happen if I did this...

Thanks if someone can give me a dummy answer that I'm looking for :)

Comment: Never include a .cpp file.

Comment: int __cdecl gp(void) means that gp takes no parameters - you can actually define the function with the word void ib the parameter list to mean that it takes no parameeters (but it is optional).  I think why it exists twice is because you are including gp.cpp and also compiling and linking it separately - usually you don't include other .cpp files but instead only .h files that contain only declarations (just the `int gp();` but no function body).

Answer (score 0):

Keeping apart the fact that it is better to avoid global variables (better think on a Singleton pattern, or something similar), your problem is that you are compiling the gp() function twice (one when you compile gp.cpp and one when it's included in the other file). That's the meaning of that error. To solve it you can make a header file "gp.h" such like:

```
#ifndef __GP_H__
#define __GP_H__

int gp();

#endif
```

Then in both .cpp files include that header using

```
#include "gp.h"
```

(The #ifndef and so on is just to avoid the header file to be included twice in the same file).

With this you're declaring the function, but not "implementing" it, so the compiler will generate the binary code only once.

Comment: BTW, cdecl is the calling convention of the function (this one is **C declaration**). A calling convention establishes how a subroutine receives the parameters at low-level implementation.

Comment: Identifiers starting with underscores are reserved (actually the rules are more complicated … just go with this one). Your code is thus wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, code is normally divided into *header files* and *implementation files*. Headers typically have the extension `.h` (or `.hh` or `.hpp` for C++), and implementation files have extensions like `.c`, `.cc` or `.cpp`.

Implementation files are the things that actually get passed to the compiler. Header files, on the other hand, get `#include`'d into implementation files. `#include` tells the compiler (technically the preprocessor) to literally copy-and-paste the header file into the implementation. One particular header file might get included in many implementations, and headers can include other headers when necessary.

Generally, you put function *declarations* into your header files, and function *definitions* into your implementation files. A declaration looks like this:

```
int multiply(int a, int b);
```

That is, it has no body[1]. A definition, on the other hand, has a function body in curly braces, like this:

```
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

You can *declare* a function as many times as you like, provided all the declarations are identical. In C++ (and in newer versions of C), you **must** declare a function before you call it. But, importantly,  you can only ever provide one *definition* -- this is something called the **One Definition Rule**, which is what's causing the problem here.

What you need to do is to put the *declaration* of `int gp()` into a header file (called, say, `gp.hpp`, and `#include` that in the file that defines `shop()`.

As it stands, the compiler is first compiling `gp.cpp`, and creating code for `int gp()`. Then it's copying-and-pasting `gp.cpp` into your other file and trying to create a second bit of code also called `int gp()`. When it tries to combine these together into an executable, it sees it has two things (technically called *symbols*) with the same name, and you get the linker error you're seeing.

(Later, you might find you want to put definitions into a header file using the `inline` keyword, but for the moment it's probably best to separate out your code.)

[1]: For the purists: yes, I know, a definition is also a declaration :-)